# Make lists between two unique characters [python]

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a file named text2.txt that looks like this:

```
20.0.60.129/29
20.0.60.129
20.0.60.130
20.0.60.131
20.0.60.132
20.0.60.133
20.0.60.134
20.56.32.78/29
20.56.32.73
20.56.32.74
20.56.32.75
20.56.32.76
20.56.32.77
20.56.32.78
20.0.100.73/29
20.0.100.73
20.0.100.0
20.0.100.75
20.0.100.76
20.0.100.77
20.0.100.78
20.0.241.30/29
```

The code I have right now is this:

```
import ipaddress
import pprint
import re

lines = []
char1 = '/'
char2 = '/'
with open("text2.txt", 'r') as file:    
    for line in file:

        sep = (line[line.find(char1)+1 : line.find(char2)])     
        lines.append(sep.strip())

pprint.pprint(lines)
```

The result i get right now looks like this

```
['',
 '20.0.60.129',
 '20.0.60.130',
 '20.0.60.131',
 '20.0.60.132',
 '20.0.60.133',
 '20.0.60.134',
 '',
 '20.56.32.73',
 '20.56.32.74',
 '20.56.32.75',
 '20.56.32.76',
 '20.56.32.77',
 '20.56.32.78',
 '',
 '20.0.100.73',
 '20.0.100.0',
 '20.0.100.75',
 '20.0.100.76',
 '20.0.100.77',
 '20.0.100.78',
 '']
```

I want to have a result that looks like this: 
(between every empty line the code should start a new list)

```
['20.0.60.129',
'20.0.60.130',
'20.0.60.131',
'20.0.60.132',
'20.0.60.133',
'20.0.60.134']

['20.56.32.73',
'20.56.32.74',
'20.56.32.75',
'20.56.32.76',
'20.56.32.77',
'20.56.32.78']

['20.0.100.73'
'20.0.100.0',
'20.0.100.75'
'20.0.100.76'
'20.0.100.77'
'20.0.100.78']
```

Comment: Is each each group always 6 elements?

Comment: no it is not, it depends on wich subnet there is on the IP address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you request

> between every empty line the code should start a new list

you could use:

```
t = ['',
 '20.0.60.129',
 '20.0.60.130',
 '20.0.60.131',
 '20.0.60.132',
 '20.0.60.133',
 '20.0.60.134',
 '',
 '20.56.32.73',
 '20.56.32.74',
 '20.56.32.75',
 '20.56.32.76',
 '20.56.32.77',
 '20.56.32.78',
 '',
 '20.0.100.73',
 '20.0.100.0',
 '20.0.100.75',
 '20.0.100.76',
 '20.0.100.77',
 '20.0.100.78',
 '']


def get_result(t):
    # new list each time c == ""
    r = []
    for c in t:
        if c == "":
            yield r
            r = [] # reset list
        else:
            r.append(c)

for l in get_result(t):
    if l:
        print(l)

['20.0.60.129', '20.0.60.130', '20.0.60.131', '20.0.60.132', '20.0.60.133', '20.0.60.134']
['20.56.32.73', '20.56.32.74', '20.56.32.75', '20.56.32.76', '20.56.32.77', '20.56.32.78']
['20.0.100.73', '20.0.100.0', '20.0.100.75', '20.0.100.76', '20.0.100.77', '20.0.100.78']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final_lines = [] 
for l in lines:
    if l == "":  
       newline = []
       if len(newline) != 0:
           final_lines.append(newline)
    else:
        newline.append(l)
```

I am making a list of list. As there is a "" in lines, I append the list made till then to final_lines else keep on adding the value to newline till the "" is encountered again in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get index of '' values:
indexes = [i for i, v in enumerate(lines) if v == '']

# Return lists by slicing main list
for index, _ in enumerate(indexes[:-1]):
    print lines[indexes[index] + 1:indexes[index + 1]]
```